# Loading a custom UIView from a XIB file within a XIB for a ViewController view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, interface-builder, xib

I have an `WizardSequenceViewController` with an `IBOutlet WizardView *_wizardView`. In many `WizardSequenceViewController.xib` file I have the `view` outlet connected to the File's Owner - `WizardSequenceViewController`. I have a subview of that view defined with the class attribute set to `WizardView`. I have connected that `WizardView` to the outlet in the File's Owner. Finally, in my `WizardView.xib` I have a `UILabel` that I have placed in the file to test if the view is being rendered. When I select the `WizardSequenceViewController` from my tab bar, I see the superview `view` but not the subview `_wizardView`. When I set a breakpoint in my `-(id)initWithCoder` method in my `WizardView.m` file I see it stop there, so I know that it is calling that initializer (and thus it *should* be using the xib to load that file). I have tried many iterations and variations to get this thing to work but I can't and I am going crazy. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `initWithNibName:@"WizardView"`?

Comment: @Wienke, why would I need to call that if I have set the outlet for `_wizardView` and I know it is calling the `initWithCoder` initializer for `WizardView`?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that nibs were considered to have been encoded. I've always used the nibName when loading them. It was just an idea for a simple thing to try. Perhaps you could call `initWithNibName` *from* `initWithCoder`.

Comment: Actually, why not simply call a `present` method on the outlet?

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by a `present`  method?

Comment: What I was thinking was that you shouldn't have to call *any* init method if it's an outlet; outlets are initialized along with their class. But I was wrong to suggest a `present` method, which is for presenting the view of another *controller*. There doesn't seem to be any other way presenting an IB-prepared view. I wonder if your basic design of nested xib views conflicts with the iOS view scheme...

Answer (score 0):

From Apple doc "View Controller Basics, About Custom View Controllers":

> The one-to-one correspondence between a view controller and the views in its view hierarchy is the key design consideration. You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions of the same view hierarchy. Similarly, you should not use a single custom view controller object to manage multiple screens worth of content.
>
> Note: If you want to divide a view hierarchy into multiple subareas and manage each one separately, use generic controller objects (custom objects descending from NSObject) instead of view controller objects to manage each subarea. Then use a single view controller object to manage the generic controller objects.

Maybe you can't do a view-and-subview outlet setup in a view controller. And I'm not sure assigning the subview outlet to a separate NSObject subclass would work either, because how would you present it? Could you write your subview programmatically, using initWithFrame and addSubview, instead of making it an outlet? Or, if you really want to set it up graphically, could you assign it to a separate view controller as owner? Then the top view controller will call `presentModal` on the sub view controller. Or, if all you need is a UILabel as a subview, just add the label to the main view?

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced a similar issue. But got it resolved by following steps given in the following link. Hope it helps.
 http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2012/07/09/an-update-on-nested-nib-loading